# Converting XML tags to Hexadecimal

Tags: xml, character-encoding, biztalk, urlencode

We have an external system we are trying to connect to than only accepts XML payload that has been encoded in Hexadecimal.

```
For example;
<   3C
>   3E
/   2F
"   22
```

What would be the best way to handle this in BizTalk? Also, it should only replace the tags and not the data. Currently running BizTalk 2016

Comment: That makes no sense.  How does it tell the difference between an encoded tag and actual content that happens to be valid hex digits?

Comment: There will be '%' before the tag. For example;

<SSN> 123-456-7890 </SSN>
would be converted to
%3CSSN%3E123-456-7890%3C%2F%3E

Makes sense?

Comment: First, are you **absolutely sure** this is a real requirement and there is no way around it?  This is so off the wall, it's...well...hard to believe.

Comment: Hahaha.. I am 1000%. The reason we are doing this is because of their system's security concerns. From what I sensing, this has to be done on the pipeline. I have tested sending the payload via postman and it's only working once we've converted it to hex.
That being said, how would I go about developing something like this on the pipeline before it gets to the send port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So...first, yes, you're right to think this is a bit silly and doesn't help with 'security' one bit :( ... actually, it raises my concern about security...

The next think you need to do is tell you management that because of their very, very unusual and unnecessary requirement, you will have to spend extra time and their money accommodating this receiver.  *This is not a problem with BizTalk Server.*

Finally, the correct way to handle this is in an Encoding Pipeline Component.  The actually implementation is pretty simple, you have to read the Stream byte by byte, writing the escaped markup characters to the output stream.

Answer (score 1):

Do you send your payload as Hexadecimal text? You have several options, the most accurate maybe implement an Assembler that change the XML characters to equivalent hexadecimal value, add it to a Send Pipeline and use the Send Pipeline on your send port.

Comment: Yes, I send the payload as Hexadecimal text. Just the tags though, not the actual text. 
SSN> 123-456-7890 </SSN> 

will be sent as 

 %3CSSN%3E123-456-7890%3C%2F%3E

I am very new to BizTalk and never played around with assemblers. Let me google around and see. Thanks.

Comment: You generate a Flat File? Or you are calling an external web service?

Comment: I am calling a web service.

Comment: But then this Hexadecimal text is a parameter of the Web Service?

Comment: No, it's the payload itself. We have to encode to payload and replace the tags to the Hexadecimal representation. For example, this xmk for SSN <SSN> 123-456-7890 </SSN> would be converted to %3CSSN%3E123-456-7890%3C%2F%3E .

Making sense?

Comment: Does not make sense, unless you do not use a WS and you are using another type of protocol to send that data strip, as to TCP / IP adapter.

Comment: It's definitely web service as response we are getting back is xml. It's just that when we are sending, we have to encode the tags in Hex.